# Codeigniter Ajax Datatable showing Error

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I have referred this link to make my codeigniter datatable ajax based datatable.

> http://mbahcoding.com/tutorial/php/codeigniter/codeigniter-simple-server-side-datatable-example.html

But it is showing error and not showing the data in datatable.

**Message: Undefined index: length**

**Message: Undefined index: start**

**Message: Undefined index: draw**

Please someone help me to remove these errors.

My Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      //Ajax Datatable
      //datatables
    var dataTable = $('#dataTables-suburb').DataTable({ 

        processing: true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
        serverSide: true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
        order: [], //Initial no order.

        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        ajax: {
            url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/states/state_table_ajax')?>",
            type: "POST"
        },

        //Set column definition initialisation properties.
        columnDefs: [
        { 
            targets: [ 0 ], //first column / numbering column
            orderable: false, //set not orderable
        },
        ],


    });  
});
```

My Controller Function

```
public function state_table_ajax()
    {
       $data['details'] = $this->LoginModel->admin_details($this->session->userdata('admin-username'));
       foreach($data['details'] as $detail):
       $country_id = $detail['country_id'];
    endforeach;
        $states = $this->StatesModel->get_states_table($country_id);

        $no = $_POST['start'];

        foreach($states as $state):
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            $row[] = $no;
            $row[] = $state['id'];
            $row[] = $state['state_name'];
            //$row[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$state['id'].'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Update</button>';  
            //$row[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$state['id'].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</button>';  
            $state_data[] = $row;
        endforeach;

        $output = array(
                "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                "recordsTotal" => $this->StatesModel->get_states_count($country_id),
                "recordsFiltered" => $this->StatesModel->get_states_count_filtered($country_id),
                "data" => $state_data,
        );
        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($output);
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

My Model Code

```
public function get_states($country_id)
    {
        $order_column = array('id', 'state_name');
        $this->db->select('id, state_name')
                           ->where('country_id', $country_id, FALSE)
                           ->from('tbl_states');

        //For Search value Datatable
        if(isset($_POST['search']['value'])) 
        {
            $this->db->like('state_name', $_POST['search']['value']);
        }
        //For Order Datatable
        if(isset($_POST['order']))
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->order_column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        }
        else  
        {  
            $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');  
        }

        //$result = $query->result_array();
        //return $result;
    }
    //Get Datatable
    public function get_states_table($country_id)
    {
        $this->get_states($country_id);
        if($_POST["length"] != -1)
        {
            $this->db->limit($_POST["length"], $_POST["start"]);
            $query = $this->db->where('country_id', $country_id, FALSE)
                              ->get();
            return $query->result_array();
        }
    }
    function get_states_count_filtered($country_id)
    {
        $this->get_states($country_id);
        $query = $this->db->where('country_id', $country_id, FALSE)
                          ->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
    public function get_states_count($country_id)  
    {  
       $this->db->where('country_id', $country_id, FALSE)
                ->from('tbl_states'); 


       return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show your Html and Jquery code

Comment: Now showing this one becoz i have called the ajax in another function and view in another. DataTables warning: table id=dataTables-suburb - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Comment: They have provided the link which shows what error is about and how can we solve it.

Comment: Sorry can't solve I am new on that. I have updated my view jquery , controller code and model code. Please check

Comment: Please check that are you returning anything in model's "get_states" function or not ?

Comment: given model code no return from that function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150108/discussion-between-ketan-solanki-and-binayak-das).

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

from

```
$no = $_POST['start'];
```

To

```
if(isset($_POST['start']) && isset($_POST['draw']))
{   
  $no = $_POST['start'];
}else{
     // need start and draw 
     die(); // some error 
}
```

and in your model

From

```
if($_POST["length"] != -1)
```

To

```
if(isset($_POST["length"]) && $_POST["length"] != -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Model Code like this :

```
public function get_states($country_id)
    {
        $order_column = array('id', 'state_name');

        $this->db->select('id, state_name');
        $this->db->from('tbl_states'); 
        $this->db->where('country_id', $country_id);
        //For Search value Datatable
        if(isset($_POST['search']['value'])) 
        {
            $this->db->like('state_name', $_POST['search']['value']);
        }
        //For Order Datatable
        if(isset($_POST['order']))
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->order_column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        }
        else  
        {  
            $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');  
        }
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }
    //Get Datatable
    public function get_states_table($country_id,$length,$start)
    {
        $this->get_states($country_id);
        if($length != -1)
        {
            $this->db->limit($length, $start);
            $query = $this->db->where('country_id', $country_id, FALSE)
                              ->get();
            return $query->result_array();
        }
    }
    function get_states_count_filtered($country_id)
    {
        $this->get_states($country_id);
        $query = $this->db->where('country_id', $country_id, FALSE)
                          ->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
    public function get_states_count($country_id)  
    {  
       $this->db->where('country_id', $country_id, FALSE)
                ->from('tbl_states'); 


       return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }
```

And in the controller call this function :

```
get_states_table()
```

like this :

where

```
$length = $_POST['length'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
get_states_table($country_id,$length,$start)
```